# iPhone | How do I create a unique key from an NSTimeInterval?

Tags: iphone

I need to convert an NSTimeInterval into a unique key. What is the best practice for doing this?

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: It would help if you specified what you needed the key for and if you have any length requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSTimeInterval is just a double.  This means you can use any standard hash function to generate a key.

Answer (score 0):

`NSTimeInterval` is declared as `typedef double NSTimeInterval;`, it's not an object, so you can get the same value by calling different methods.